# NVRAM data is reset to 0 when using NVIC_SystemReset()

Tags: ram, non-volatile-memory

I am working on nRF52840 with Mbed5.15. Trying to persist data in NVRAM.
In the linker script `nRF52840.ld` I have something like this:

```
MEMORY
{
  BLAH (rw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x200
  NVRAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000200, LENGTH = 0x400
  RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000600, LENGTH = 0x8000
}

SECTIONS
{
  .nvdata :
  {
    *(.nvdata)
  } > NVRAM

  .data :
  {
    *(.data)
  } > RAM AT > flash

  .bss :
  {
    *(.bss)
  } > RAM

  .text :
  {
    *(.text)
  } > flash
}

__nvdata_start = ADDR(.nvdata);
__nvdata_end = ADDR(.nvdata) + SIZEOF(.nvdata);
```

In c++11 source code, I have:

```
__attribute__((section(".nvdata")))
uint32_t test_var;
```

If I set the value of `test_var` in my app and use `NVIC_SystemReset()` to reboot my application, the value of the `test_var` is reset to zero. However, if I run code with `int a = 1/0;`, somewhere my code triggers the divide-by-zero exception to reboot my app, and the value of `test_var` persists.

How to persist data in NVRAM with CMSIS's `NVIC_SystemReset()`?

I know I am creating a section of 1024-byte RAM for storing an 8-byte integer. It is a test.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I can't find anything in the datasheet that suggests that the nRF52840 has non-volatile memory at that region. Can you tell us where you found that information?

Comment: https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_PS_v1.7.pdf page 22

Comment: That memory map says 0x20000000 is SRAM. SRAM is volatile.

Comment: The linker script changes the layout of the memory, so the .map is changed. The data should just be persisted in the RAM if a battery is connected. When the app is soft reset, the customized section should stay unchanged. If you ask chatGPT, it can generate a whole example of how to do that.

Comment: You're confusing non-volatile RAM with a C non-initialized section. If the hardware doesn't have NVRAM, then simply naming a C section ".nvdata" isn't going to magically turn normal SRAM into non-volatile RAM.

Comment: You are right about the definition of NVRAM. In my case, the product I am working on will always have a battery connected. So for this specific product, the RAM is NV.

Comment: No MCU I've ever worked with allows you to remap memory without also writing to some MMU-related register. Just changing the linker script won't do, that will tell the _compiler_ where to place things but it won't tell the _microcontroller_ as much. As for ChatGPT it's a lie generator, it knows nothing of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that can reset the RAM.

1. Setting the SOC to a low power state (called "on" and "off" mode here) when data retention is not configured. See page 69 of the [datasheet](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_PS_v1.1.pdf).
   [image]Maybe a low power state is entered somewhere during reset. Hard to tell witout seeing all the code.
2. The default [reset handler](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_NORDIC/TARGET_NRF5x/TARGET_NRF52/TARGET_MCU_NRF52840/device/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_NRF52840.S) of mbed os copies memory from flash to RAM. Since you didn't provide the complete linker script, it's hard to tell if your changes are effective in preventing your "non-volatile" section from being overwritten.
3. The bootloader may also reset or overwrite some part of the RAM. Again, hard to tell without the knowing exactly what bootloader is used and what it does.
4. There is a bug in the silicon that seems to affect memory retention. [See errata 115](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Ferrata_nRF52840_EngA%2FERR%2FnRF52840%2FEngineeringA%2Flatest%2Fanomaly_840_115.html).

In general, if you want to retain data, it’s better to use true non-volatile memory. The SOC has flash memory, which is non-volatile. Usually vendors will provide examples for writing data to flash during runtime. On NXP micros it's called IAP (in application programming), but Nodric may use a different term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found there are multiple linker scripts, and another linker script defined the memory layout again, which fits your point 3. Cheers.